# How to use the group method properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an Rails 3.2 webapp and in this app I got a statistics function.
I want to generate a output with how much revenue a certain task has generated (for a selected user) and group the sums by day within this date range.

How can I do this? I have created a class method on the Task model:

```
def self.earnings (params)
 earnings = group("date(created_at)")
 earnings = earnings.where("user_id = ?", params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id].present?
 earnings = earnings.completed.sum(:item_value).round
 earnings
end
```

And in the users controller I got this method call:

```
def employees
 if params[:search]
    @statistics = Task.earnings(params)
 end
end
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "tasks.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...ser_id = '13') GROUP BY date(created_at) ORDER BY created_at...
                                                             ^
: SELECT SUM("tasks"."item_value") AS sum_item_value, date(created_at) AS date_created_at FROM "tasks"  WHERE "tasks"."account_id" = 4 AND "tasks"."status" = 'completed' AND (user_id = '13') GROUP BY date(created_at) ORDER BY created_at DESC):
```

Comment: Do you use by any chance a default scope to order by created_at field?

Comment: Yes, should I remove it?

Comment: Try to remove it, and check the result. It may be the cause of your problem, as there is no other order command in your query.

Comment: What `completed` is doing there ? I think I have the answer. But without knowing `completed`, I can't give the answer.